# How to get a branch with composer

Tags: git, composer-php

Hi I'm really new to composer.
I am using this repo: https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk
I ran this command in my project: composer require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk
Composer installed version 2.2.0

```
{
    "require": {
        "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "^2.2"
    }
}
```

But when I listed the files in vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/ I just had these files:

```
Actions.php  
Commands    
FileUpload   
Laravel  
TelegramClient.php   
TelegramResponse.php Api.php      
Exceptions  
HttpClients  
Objects  
TelegramRequest.php
```

but as you see [here](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/tree/master/src) there are a lot more files. I checked branches:
github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/branches
and found out that composer is installing "2.0" branch but I want it to use "master" branch . How can I do that?

Comment: What does your composer.json file contains? Probably the 2.0 is a tag not a branch

Comment: Which file do you need?

Comment: @frz3993 tnx for your reply. I added my composer.json

Comment: @Sven I need src/Keyboard

Comment: If you want to install a branch, change the require to branchname-dev, like master-dev

Comment: @frz3993 That worked thanks! Would you please write it as an answer so that I can choose it as the best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting a branch, you should require the branchname -dev, eg `master-dev`. But note that some will commit their newest update to the master branch which could break backward compatibility.

Comment: It is just in the opposite way. `dev-master`and `dev-develop`. 
Execute on the command line to get the master branch:

`composer require --dev  irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk:dev-master`